# Can I only run RSpec and Autotest without Cucumber?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, cucumber, autotest

I am using both Cucumber and Rspec but I want to disable autotest from running the stories while I"m working on the spec examples. Is there a configuration option I can change to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you have `AUTOFEATURE=true` defined in your environment?  This is what controls whether autotest includes the cucumber tests or not. The default should be false but in any case you can override it by starting autotest with:

```
AUTOFEATURE=false autotest
```